# Login/Register in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hye Guys,
I have two scene where user can register and another scene where they can login. My register details are successfully going in the database. Now im stuck in login scene, i want a functionality through which i can insert new details from register in login.
I cant even print the content present in table. Below is my code
Can anyone help me in this?

```
    Mobile1= db:nrows("SELECT * FROM Mobile")
    for k,v,z in pairs(Mobile1) do
        print(k,v,z)
    end
```

Mobile is my table in sqlite

Comment: You are using pairs in wrong way. What is “z”? Could you also show structure of your Mobile1 table?

Comment: Thanks for your reply wsha. I have fixed that part. Also,'z ' is not required that was my bad.
Now im trying to implement that functionality in which app will Relaunch by user input.